# What are the advantages of adding a like button specifcally for your website if you already have a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, connections

What are the advantages of adding a like button specifcally for  your website if you already have a facebook page?

What i mean is say you have a facebook page for your product, and you include a like button on your website for that facebook page. Is there much point adding a like button specifically for the website as well?

The only advantage i can think of is if users like both the page and the website, it will generate an extra message in their friends news feeds, so help publicise your product a bit more.

I guess another advantage might be if facebook shuts down your facebook page for whatever reason, at least you should still have the likes for the website.

Anyone got any other good reasons for it?

Comment: Inappropriate for this site, try webmasters.stackexchange instead

Answer (score 3):

Some people may find your webpage before finding you Facebook page.

Do you have a like button or like box on your webpage?
If you have a like box, visitors to your site could see images of their friends who have liked your site.

Answer (score 2):

By adding "like" buttons to all your content you drastically increase the amount of exposure you can get on Facebook from "likes" simply by the increase in things that can be "liked".

Answer (score 2):

No, I think that's about the best reason, so people can tell their friends about a site, without having to copy or type the url into their facebook etc.